# Issue with subscript (script instantiated and called from another script) only running the called function, but not the entire script

Tags: python

Goal: From the superscript, per each iteration of the for loop, send a list to a function in the subscript, update that list, exit the function in the subscript, and perform several actions, then onto the next iteration.

Issue: Only the function I call from the superscript is run and not the entire subscript.

CrossValidationSmall.py (superscript)

```
import subfileTest

data = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J','K']
n = 2

for start in range(0, len(data), n):
    stop = start + n
    test = data[start: stop]
    train = data[:start] + data[stop:]
    subfileTest.set_train_data(train)
```

subfileTest.py (subscript)

```
train_data = []

def set_train_data(train):
    global train_data
    train_data = train

print(train_data) #should output the lists each time subfileTest is called.
```

Expected Output

```
MacBook-Pro:SmallerEnviromentTest Me$ python CrossValidationSmall.py
['C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K']
['A', 'B', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K']
['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K']
['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'I', 'J', 'K']
['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'K']
['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J']
```

Current Output

```
MacBook-Pro:SmallerEnviromentTest Me$ python CrossValidationSmall.py
[]
```

Comment: why print() is not in the function (set_train_data) ? I think the output [] is called when `import subfileTest`. Try calling print in function `set_train_data`

Comment: @hughugh Is there not a way that I could call the entire subscript? But the print function is just there to see if the list is updated and there'll be hundreds of functions from the subscript that I'd prefer not to individually call from the superscript.

Comment: Then make a function just get global train_data and print it. And call that function in the superscript.

Comment: @hughugh I don't understand why I'd want to make a function get global train_data and print it. The train_data will be used by several functions inside of the subscript. The superscript is supposed to be a for loop that feeds a list to the subscript, the train_data list is updated, it performs actions wherever that variable is used, then closes, then next iteration of the for loop from the superscript repeats that.

Comment: scripts are executed directly when you import them into diff module/script. i guess you need to wrap it into a function so that you can print it AFTER you've finished processing. have all your processing in one script: declaring train_data and adding in all your chunks. then make use of the list from other scripts by importing.

Comment: You can `def call_all_others():` and hardcode a call to every function you want, then you can put just one line in your superscript

Answer (score 2):

From what I understood, you need your subscript to be called in entirety on every iteration.

Here's the thing:

- A new module once found is executed and module from the initial execution is **cached**.
- When the same module is imported in a different file, the cached version is returned.
- This cached version lives throughout the lifetime of the process.

Since you need you subscript to be run fresh on each iteration, a Class can be used. an object of the class to:

- Store data from each iteration
- Write any number of functions that work with this data
- Retain values from each object as long as you need

**Superscript**:

```py
from subscript import ModelCrossValidator

trial = 0

data = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K']
n = 2

for start in range(0, len(data), n):
    trial += 1

    stop = start + n
    test = data[start: stop]

    # train_subset to be used for cross validation
    train_subset = data[:start] + data[stop:]

    cross_validator = ModelCrossValidator(train_subset)
    cross_val_score = cross_validator.calc_score()

print("CrossValSet: {}, Data: {}, Score: {:.2}".format(trial, cross_validator.data, cross_val_score))
```

**Subscript**:

```py
import random

class ModelCrossValidator:

    def __init__(self, train_subset):
        self.data = train_subset     # your folded cross-val data
        self.model = None            # can pass in a model too here
        self.accuracy = 0            # other fields that you might need

    def calc_score(self):
        # you can have any number of functions like this.
        # all will deal with only the data from a single object.

        self.accuracy = 0.8 + (random.random()) % 0.2
        return self.accuracy
```

Output:

```sh
Macbook-Pro: chimichanga$ python superscript.py 
CrossValSet: 1, Data: ['C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K'], Score: 0.89
CrossValSet: 2, Data: ['A', 'B', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K'], Score: 0.94
CrossValSet: 3, Data: ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K'], Score: 0.9
CrossValSet: 4, Data: ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'I', 'J', 'K'], Score: 0.84
CrossValSet: 5, Data: ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'K'], Score: 0.88
CrossValSet: 6, Data: ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J'], Score: 0.94
```